# How to change the date format of v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a Vue.js project using Vuetify, and I'm encountering an issue with the default date format of the `v-text-field` with the type "date." Currently, the format is mm/dd/yyyy, but I need it to be yyyy/mm/dd.

Here's the code for the date field:

```html
<v-text-field
  type="date"
  label="From Date"
  v-model="from_date"
  ref="fromDateField"
></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <v-menu
    v-model="menu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    :nudge-right="40"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
  >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="formattedDate"
        label="From Date"
        readonly
        v-on="on"
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker v-model="from_date" @input="menu = false"></v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menu: false,
      from_date: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    formattedDate() {
      if (!this.from_date) return null;
      const [year, month, day] = this.from_date.split('-');
      return `${year}/${month}/${day}`;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```